# On the equality of integrals of complex valued functions.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f,g$ be some nonconstant, differentiable and complex-valued functions of $x$. If

$\int_a^c f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_a^c g(x) \mathrm{d}x $

Should there necessarily exist some $b$ in $[a,c]$ such that $f(b) =g(b)$ ?

I know this holds for real valued $f,g$, but can't seem to find an explanation for the complex case. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Or take $f(x)=e^{ix}$ and $g(x)=2e^{ix}$ for $x\in [0,2\pi]$

Explanation: If you look at real and complex parts separately then you will have equality at certain places. But they do not occur simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $a=0,c=1$, and

$$f(x) = x$$

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2}+i\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)(x-1)$$

Unless I screwed up somewhere, these both integrate to $\frac{1}{2}$, and the only points where $g$ is real are $\frac{1}{3}$ and $1$, where $f(x) \neq \frac{1}{2}$.